# Is passlib.hash.sha256_crypt adequate for storing user pwds?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sha256

I am experimenting with the [passlib.hash.sha256_crypt](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.html) algorithm in an App Engine app and it seems rather simple to implement.

Is this secure enough with it's default parameters of autogenerated salt and 80,000 rounds? Should it first be padded with random chars?

Password is being posted in from a form and encrypted as above.

Answer (score 2):

I can't judge what "secure enough" means.

Last I read the best options were scrypt, bcrypt, or pbkdf2. If you can't use those then I recommend sha512 with many thousands of iterations. One of the benefits of using passlib CryptContext is you can update your scheme later as needed (and as better implementations become available) while keeping easy compatibility with previously stored passwords. sha512_crypt is very easy to implement on GAE with passlib CryptContext.

I'm not sure padding with characters (on top of salting) adds anything.